# Chrome cast not receiving messages

Tags: javascript, android, casting, chromecast

I'm trying to send a message to my custom receiver for ChromeCast. I use the following code in my Android app to send a code to the receiver;

```
Cast.CastApi.sendMessage(mApiClient, "urn:x-cast:move", "TEST");
```

On the receiving side I have the following code;

```
window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('media');
window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(window.mediaElement);
window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
window.castReceiverManager.start();

window.castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected = function(event) {
    //This is called
}

window.customMessageBus = window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('urn:x-cast:move', cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.STRING);
var defaultFunction = window.customMessageBus.onMessage;
window.customMessageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
    //This is not called
    defaultFunction(event);
};
```

As I pointed out in the code, the 'onSenderConnected' is called, so I know it connected to the app. But when I try to send a message over the custom messagebus, it doesnt give me anything. I'm completely new to android and cast, so I could be doing a thousand things wrong. Can anybody help me solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it myself. What I did wrong was starting the castReceiverManager before adding the custom namespace. So the correct code for the receiver compared to what I posted in the question would be;

```
window.mediaElement = document.getElementById('media');
window.mediaManager = new cast.receiver.MediaManager(window.mediaElement);
window.castReceiverManager = cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager.getInstance();
//Removed the start here

window.castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected = function(event) {
    //OnConnect
}

window.customMessageBus = window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('urn:x-cast:move', cast.receiver.CastMessageBus.MessageType.STRING);
var defaultFunction = window.customMessageBus.onMessage;
window.customMessageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
    //OnMessage
    defaultFunction(event);
};

//Start at the end
window.castReceiverManager.start();
```